# Image not rendered on DXA site

Tags: dxa

i have setup demo DXA site everything looks fine  but carousel and image are not rendered on site it shows message "A problem occurred while rendering this seection". i have set image publishing in broker

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextEngine..ctor()
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_ContextEngine()
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.CalculateScreenWidth()
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_ScreenWidth()
>      at ASP._Page_Areas_Core_Views_Entity_Partials_Teaser_ImageOverlay_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\DXASite\Areas\Core\Views\Entity\Partials\Teaser-ImageOverlay.cshtml:line 8
>      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>      at ASP._Page_Areas_Core_Views_Entity_Carousel_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\DXASite\Areas\Core\Views\Entity\Carousel.cshtml:line 20
>      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>      at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

[image]

Comment: Please paste the logs here at "C:\Temp\logs\site.log" (by default).

Comment: @SaurabhGangwar i have updated log in question

Answer (score 1):

The exception happens in the ContextEngine constructor, which retrieves the context claims from the Ambient Data Framework. So, probably the ADF is not properly configured.